# Write struct into file in c

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to write struct to file. I have done the part where I defined struct I read text from file and then I saved it in struct now I am on a point where I want to make change in struct: `students[i].name` and then I want the change to be reflected (write) in file but it has invalid encoding.

**file.txt** has this structure:

```
U,Virat Kohli,Virat Kohli,
U,Serena Williams,Virat Kohli,
G,Wayne Gretzky,Virat Kohli,
U,Virat Kohli,Virat Kohli,
U,Serena Williams,Virat Kohli,
G,Wayne Gretzky,Virat Kohli,
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    // members for the student's type, name, surname
    char type;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
} Student;

int main(void)
{
    // for comparing strcmp
    int result;

    // file pointer variable for accessing the file
    FILE *file;

    // attempt to open file.txt in read mode to read the file contents
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    // if the file failed to open, exit with an error message and status
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // array of structs for storing the Student data from the file
    Student students[100];

    // read will be used to ensure each line/record is read correctly
    int read = 0;

    // records will keep track of the number of Student records read from the file
    int records = 0;

    // read all records from the file and store them into the students array
    while (fscanf(file, " %c , %49[^,], %49[^,],", &students[records].type, students[records].name, students[records].surname) == 3)
    {
        // if fscanf read 3 values from the file then we've successfully read
        records++;
        // if there was an error reading from the file exit with an error message
        // and status
        if (ferror(file))
        {
            printf("Error reading file.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // close the file as we are done working with it
    fclose(file);

    // print out the number of records read
    printf("\n%d records read.\n\n", records);

    // print out each of the records that was read
    for (int i = 0; i < records; i++)
        printf("%c %s %s\n",
               students[i].type,
               students[i].name,
               students[i].surname);
    printf("\n");

    // change first record's name to Elena Heis
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        if (students[i].name == students[i].name)
        {
            printf("%s\n",
                   students[i].name);
            strcpy(students[i].name, "Elena Heis");
            printf("%s\n",
                   students[i].name);
        }
    }

    // write changes to file
    file = fopen("file.txt", "wb");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(students, sizeof(Student), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After write file has broken encoding like this
[image]

It should be
[image]

Comment: In `if (students[i].name == students[i].name)` you cannot compare a string like that in C, ...but with *itself*? And at the end, it isn't going to work just dumping the first array element to the text file, using `fwrite`. It contains all the unused string space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is clean and your format string is almost perfect, yet parsing the **csv** file (or any file in general) with `fscanf()` is not recommended as it is very difficult to recover from errors and newlines are mostly indistinguishable from other white space characters. In particular, the `\n` at the end of the format string will match any possibly empty sequence of white space characters.

Testing `ferror()` and `feof()` as you do seems fine but insufficient to ensure reliable parsing: if `fscanf()` returns a short code, for example because of an empty field, parsing will continue from the middle of the offending line and neither `ferror()` nor `feof()` will cause the loop to end.

You should instead read one line at a time with `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` to parse the line.

Also note these remarks:

- the **csv** file does not seem to contain `name` and `surname` fields but rather the full names of opponents.
- this file seems to have trailing `,` after the third field. If this is expected, the format string ensuring record validity should be changed to `"%c,%49[^,],%49[^,\n]%1[,\n]"`
- you should check that `records < 100` to avoid a buffer overflow.
- the test `if (students[i].name == students[i].name)` is useless and always true. No test is needed to change the name of the first student.
- you cannot write the text file with `fwrite(students, sizeof(Student), 1, file)`, you should instead use `fprintf` as for the output to the terminal.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    // members for the student's type, name, surname
    char type;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
} Student;

int main(void)
{
    // file pointer variable for accessing the file
    FILE *file;

    // attempt to open file.txt in read mode to read the file contents
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    // if the file failed to open, exit with an error message and status
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s for reading: %s\n", "file.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // array of structs for storing the Student data from the file
    Student students[100];

    // length of the students array
    int nrecords = sizeof(students) / sizeof(*students);

    // buffer to read one line at a time
    char buffer[256];

    // records will keep track of the number of Student records read from the file
    int records = 0;

    // read all records from the file and store them into the students array
    while (records < nrecords && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file))
    {
        // Read a line/record from the file
        // if it was able to read successfully which we expect read will be 3
        char newline[3]; // for characters at end of line: `,\n` or `\n`
        char extra;      // to ensure no more characters are present
        // there are 5 conversion specifiers, but sscanf should parse
        // exactly 4 fields, including the trailing `,` and the newline
        int read = sscanf(buffer,
                          "%c,%49[^,],%49[^,\n]%2[,\n]%c",
                          &students[records].type,
                          students[records].name,
                          students[records].surname,
                          newline, &extra);

        // if fscanf read 3 values and a newline from the file then we've successfully read
        // in another record
        if (read == 4) {
            records++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid record: %s", buffer);
        }
    }
    // if there was an error reading from the file exit with an error message
    // and status
    if (ferror(file))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    // close the file as we are done working with it
    fclose(file);

    // print out the number of records read
    printf("\n%d records read.\n\n", records);

    // print out each of the records that was read
    for (int i = 0; i < records; i++)
    {
        printf("%c %s %s\n",
               students[i].type,
               students[i].name,
               students[i].surname);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // change first record's name to Elena Heis
    strcpy(students[0].name, "Elena Heis");
    printf("%s\n", students[0].name);

    // write changes to file
    file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s for writing: %s\n", "file.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // print out each of the records that was read
    for (int i = 0; i < records; i++)
    {
        fprintf(file, "%c,%s,%s,\n",
                students[i].type,
                students[i].name,
                students[i].surname);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem with this solution is that it doesn't count the records and always displays an invalid record:. It also does not write to the file using fprintf but it outputs empty file.

Comment: @GPB: all records seem to have a trailing `,`. I have updated the answer to accept and ignore extra fields and output the extra `,`.

Comment: Thank you for the clean explanation @chqrlie :-)